# Cannot write a text in a text file using FileWriter and Printwriter

Tags: java, jtextarea, filewriter, printwriter

I want to create a program more like a **NotePad**. When you type a text inside the `JTextArea` and click **Save as**, *the program will create a text file inside the workspace with the texts typed inside the `JTextArea`.* The problem is when I click save, the program can create a text file but the texts typed inside the textarea are not saved inside the created text file. The **name** of the text file is `"Text"`. I used the `getText()` method to get the texts inside the `TextArea`.

This is the program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;    
public class TextAreaWithMenus extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextArea area;
    JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu option;
    JMenuItem menuitem;
    File file;
    FileWriter fwriter;
    PrintWriter pwriter;
    String order[] = {"Save as","Edit"};

    public TextAreaWithMenus() {
        setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(null);
        area = new JTextArea();
        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        option = new JMenu("File");
        for(String call : order) {
            menuitem = new JMenuItem(call);
            option.add(menuitem);
            menuitem.addActionListener(this);
        }
        this.add(menubar);
        menubar.setBounds(0,0,500,30);
        menubar.add(option);
        this.add(area);
        area.setBounds(0,30,500,470);
        area.setLineWrap(true);
        area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        try{
            file = new File("C://Users/LunaWorkspace/TestProject/src/Text");
            fwriter = new FileWriter(file);
            pwriter = new PrintWriter(fwriter,true);
        }catch(Exception e) {}          
        setVisible(true);
    }//END OF CONSTRUCTOR

    public void save() {
        try {   
            if(!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    pwriter.print(area.getText());
                    System.out.println(area.getText());
                    System.out.println("Saved complete");
                }catch(Exception ef) {
                    ef.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.print("Cannot Create");
                }                   
            }else if(file.exists()) {   
                    pwriter.print(area.getText());
                    System.out.println(area.getText());
                    System.out.println("Overwrite complete");   
            }
        } catch(Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Cannot Save");
        }       
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ac) {
        String act = ac.getActionCommand();         
        if(act.equals("Save as")) {
            save();
        }else if(act.equals("Edit")) {}
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                               public void run() { new TextAreaWithMenus();} });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call flush as the save is being buffered. This works:

```
public void save() {
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                pwriter.print(area.getText());
                System.out.println(area.getText());
                System.out.println("Saved complete");

            } catch (Exception ef) {
                ef.printStackTrace();
                System.err.print("Cannot Create");
            }

        } else if (file.exists()) {
            pwriter.print(area.getText());
            System.out.println(area.getText());
            System.out.println("Overwrite complete");
        }
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Cannot Save");
    } finally {
        pwriter.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between the pwriter.flush() method and pwriter.close()? I just noticed that when I tried close() method, it appears that I have to re-run the program again to overwrite the text with a new set of texts in the text file.

Comment: `flush` flushes buffers and `close` first calls flush then releases resources to let them be garbage collected. you cannot then reuse something which is closed as it will refuse rather than throw null pointer exceptions because it wiped its internal state to let the memory be reclaimed. `File` has a native file handle to the operating system. when you call close the jvm closes that handle to let the OS free that resource. there is a finite limit to how many files an operating system will let a process hold open which is why one should call `close` if you are finished with the file.

Answer (score 1):

You should close your Writer with `pwriter.close()` after finishing. Otherwise the text might not have been flushed, and nothing will be written.

Answer (score 0):

Its not good practice to create the writer in the constructor and write to it repetitive in the save method. Create a new file and writing to the old stream may leading to unexpected behavior.

Open, write to and close the stream/writer in the save method.

Then it is not necessary to check if the file already exists.
new FileWriter(file) will overwrite an existing file.